# Swift Combine: how to create custom sink?

Tags: swift, rx-swift, combine

I'm using RxSwift with something like the following

```
extension Reactive where Base: UIViewController {

    public var showError: Binder<Error> {
        return Binder(self.base) { element, error in
            let alertVC = // create UIAlertController with error
            element.present(alertVC, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

What's the best way to build something like this with Swift Combine?

Answer (score 2):

It's built in. You don't need to make a Bindable... Just do:

```
cancelable = publisher.assign(to: \.title, on: barButtonItem)
```

In answer to your edited question:

```
extension UIViewController {
    var showError: Subscribers.Sink<Error, Never> {
        return Subscribers.Sink<Error, Never>(
            receiveCompletion: { _ in },
            receiveValue: { [unowned self] error in
                let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                self.present(alertVC, animated: true)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, was a pretty bad example  I edited my post - I would like to do something custom

Comment: New question, new answer.